# Making a page unscrollable on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, css, mobile, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a page unscrollable on mobile but for some reason it's not working. On mobile, without scrolling, I can see the numbers 499 all the way down to 475. I added `overflow: hidden;` to the body, but all that did was hid the scroll bars. It doesn't actually stop the scrolling. What am I doing wrong?

```
body {
height: 2000px;
overflow: hidden;
}

<?php

$count = 500;
while ($count > 0) {
$count--;
echo $count."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the meta tags for viewport zoom level and such?

Comment: @J.A.Streich Ah. Definitely not. Can you provide the correct meta tags?

Comment: @J.A.Streich Actually. Yes. I think I am. But it doesn't have anything to do with scrolling though, does it? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check for methods to disable the scrolling for eg
setscrollable = false or something like that